# Need to create an array of all keypaths of a JS nested dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, key

Let me use this dictionary as an example; it is information from the *World Lexicon of Grammaticalization* (WLG) that I have repackaged into a nested dictionary. This particular dictionary encodes everything (?) that "do" can be grammaticalized as, that is attested in the WLG:

```js
let tDict = {
    "Causative": {},
    "Emphasis": {},
    "D-Necessity": {
        "Future": {
            "E-Necessity": {}
        },
        "B-Necessity": {
            "Future": {
                "E-Necessity": {}
            },
            "Purpose": {
                "Cause": {
                    "Adversative": {
                        "Mirative": {}
                    }
                },
                "Infinitive": {}
            }
        },
        "E-Necessity": {},
        "D-Possibility": {
            "D-Necessity": {}
        },
        "Purpose": {
            "Cause": {
                "Adversative": {
                    "Mirative": {}
                }
            },
            "Infinitive": {}
        }
    },
    "Pro-Verb": {},
    "Progressive": {
        "Habitual": {},
        "Imperfective": {},
        "Present": {}
    }
};
```

What I want is some function that takes in `tDict` and outputs a list of all maximum-depth key paths, i.e. the expected output is:

```js
[
    ["Causative"],
    ["Emphasis"],
    ["D-Necessity", "Future", "E-Necessity"],
    ["D-Necessity", "B-Necessity", "Future", "E-Necessity"],
    ["D-Necessity", "B-Necessity", "Purpose", "Cause", "Adversative", "Mirative"],
    ["D-Necessity", "B-Necessity", "Purpose", "Infinitive"],
    ["D-Necessity", "E-Necessity"],
    ["D-Necessity", "D-Possibility", "D-Necessity"],
    ["D-Necessity", "Purpose", "Cause", "Adversative", "Mirative"],
    ["D-Necessity", "Purpose", "Infinitive"],
    ["Pro-Verb"],
    ["Progressive", "Habitual"],
    ["Progressive", "Imperfective"],
    ["Progressive", "Present"]
]
```

I already have a function kicking around that computes the Cartesian product of two arrays. It can be called repeatedly with a one-element array as the first argument, such that the effect is just to concatenate the first argument onto every subarray of the second argument simultaneously:

```js
var Cartesian = (a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []);

tCart1 = Cartesian(["w"], ["x","y","z"]);
console.log("1st Cartesian Product:");
console.log(tCart1);

tCart2 = Cartesian(["v"], tCart1);
console.log("2nd Cartesian Product:");
console.log(tCart2);

tCart3 = Cartesian(["u"], tCart2);
console.log("3rd Cartesian Product:");
console.log(tCart3);
```

So my thought was to create a recursive function that exploits that property of `Cartesian`, by using it to concatenate each dictionary key onto the front of each subarray of a lower level call:

```js
function GetAllKeypaths(t) {
    return Object.keys(t).map( e => Cartesian([e], GetAllKeypaths(t[e]) ) );
}
```

This... does not work. It creates all sorts of duplicated dictionary keys all over the place, and adds a lot of additional unnecessary nesting.

It did occur to me that maybe the nesting problem is because `Cartesian` returns a nested array which just gets smooshed into a single index of the final output array because `Array.map` does a 1-to-1 mapping. So I tried dumping all the `Cartesian` outputs separately into a communal table one-by-one instead:

```js
function GetAllKeypaths(t) {
    let tOut = [];
    Object.keys(t).forEach( e => { 
        Cartesian([e], GetAllKeypaths(t[e])).forEach( e2 => { tOut.push(e2) });
    });
    return tOut;
}
```

But this doesn't work either - it returns an entirely empty array.

What should I do instead to return the desired output?

```js
let tDict = {
    "Causative": {},
    "Emphasis": {},
    "D-Necessity": {
        "Future": {
            "E-Necessity": {}
        },
        "B-Necessity": {
            "Future": {
                "E-Necessity": {}
            },
            "Purpose": {
                "Cause": {
                    "Adversative": {
                        "Mirative": {}
                    }
                },
                "Infinitive": {}
            }
        },
        "E-Necessity": {},
        "D-Possibility": {
            "D-Necessity": {}
        },
        "Purpose": {
            "Cause": {
                "Adversative": {
                    "Mirative": {}
                }
            },
            "Infinitive": {}
        }
    },
    "Pro-Verb": {},
    "Progressive": {
        "Habitual": {},
        "Imperfective": {},
        "Present": {}
    }
};

var Cartesian = (a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []);

function GetAllKeypaths(t) {
    return Object.keys(t).map( e => Cartesian([e], GetAllKeypaths(t[e]) ) );
}

console.log(GetAllKeypaths(tDict));

GetAllKeypaths = function (t) {
    let tOut = [];
    Object.keys(t).forEach( e => { 
        Cartesian([e], GetAllKeypaths(t[e])).forEach( e2 => { tOut.push(e2) });
    });
    return tOut;
}

console.log(GetAllKeypaths(tDict));
```

Comment: I am curious, what would be the value of `"purpose":{}` or `"Causative":{}` and how would it end up in the output?

Comment: @SomannaK The data structure just needs to terminate at those points, to represent "the WLG does not mention this turning into any other grammatical form". I don't particularly need it to terminate in an empty dictionary, but having the end nodes match the rest of the data structure - still being the key to some sub-dictionary - seemed like the most obvious way to make it parseable by recursion without having to explicitly write an edge case to deal with end nodes. They could just be treated like any other node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your approach with the `.forEach()`, you're trying to take the cartesian product of your key with an array that is potentially empty. If you think about a simple object such as `{a: {}}`, you're trying to perform `cartesian(['a'], [])` within your loop over the keys, which will give you an empty array. This issue propagates up through to the recursive calls, resulting in an empty array as your return value. One option would be to check that the length of the recursive call is empty, and if it is, return the current key (this is your base-case), otherwise, perform the recursive calls. In the below code, I've essentially done that, but instead, used `Object.keys()` on the object we're about to recurse on to determine whether the recursive call is going to return an empty array (we can do this, as the key paths of an empty object will be an empty array).

```js
let tDict = { "Causative": {}, "Emphasis": {}, "D-Necessity": { "Future": { "E-Necessity": {} }, "B-Necessity": { "Future": { "E-Necessity": {} }, "Purpose": { "Cause": { "Adversative": { "Mirative": {} } }, "Infinitive": {} } }, "E-Necessity": {}, "D-Possibility": { "D-Necessity": {} }, "Purpose": { "Cause": { "Adversative": { "Mirative": {} } }, "Infinitive": {} } }, "Pro-Verb": {}, "Progressive": { "Habitual": {}, "Imperfective": {}, "Present": {} } };

const cartesian = (a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []);

function getAllKeyPaths(t) {
  return Object.entries(t).flatMap(([key, val]) => Object.keys(val).length > 0 // if the current object is not "empty"
    ? cartesian([key], getAllKeyPaths(val)) // get the cartesian product of its child object's keys with this key
    : [[key]] // else, return just the current key 
  );
}

console.log(getAllKeyPaths(tDict));
```

Another approach that you could also try is a [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) one. Below, I begin by grabbing the object's entries `[[key, value], ...]` pairs.
For each key, I push the key into a `step` array, which I continue to build up with the children's object's keys by recursively calling the `helper` function. Eventually, when I hit a child object with no keys, I push this `step` array into the `res` array which is eventually returned. Each time I finish pushing a key into the `step` array and the recursive call completes, I'm also using `.pop()` on the `step` array to effectively "undo" the last key I pushed, allowing the next iteration to build another combination for the `step` array:

```js
const tDict = { "Causative": {}, "Emphasis": {}, "D-Necessity": { "Future": { "E-Necessity": {} }, "B-Necessity": { "Future": { "E-Necessity": {} }, "Purpose": { "Cause": { "Adversative": { "Mirative": {} } }, "Infinitive": {} } }, "E-Necessity": {}, "D-Possibility": { "D-Necessity": {} }, "Purpose": { "Cause": { "Adversative": { "Mirative": {} } }, "Infinitive": {} } }, "Pro-Verb": {}, "Progressive": { "Habitual": {}, "Imperfective": {}, "Present": {} } };

function getAllKeyPaths(obj) {
  const res = [];
  function helper(obj, step = []) {
    const entries = Object.entries(obj);
    if(entries.length === 0 && step.length > 0) // checking step.length handles if `getAllKeyPaths()` is called with an empty object
      res.push([...step]);

    for(const [key, val] of entries) {
      step.push(key);
      helper(val, step);
      step.pop();
    }
  }
  helper(obj);
  return res;
}

console.log(getAllKeyPaths(tDict));
```

Answer (score 0):

The function (`getPaths`) accepts an object, and the current path (default empty). It extracts the entries from the object. If the entries' length is 0, it returns the current path wrapped in an array to avoid flattering it. If there are entries, it iterates them with `Array.flapMap()`, calls the `getPaths` for each entry, passes it the value, and the value's path (previous path + new key),

```js
const getPaths = (obj, path) => {
  const entries = Object.entries(obj) // get the entries
  
  return entries.length === 0 // if entries are empty return the path wrapped in an array, so it won't be flattened
    ? [path]
    : entries.flatMap( // create the paths of the entries
        ([k, v]) => getPaths(v, [...path ?? [], k])
      )
}

const tDict = {"Causative":{},"Emphasis":{},"D-Necessity":{"Future":{"E-Necessity":{}},"B-Necessity":{"Future":{"E-Necessity":{}},"Purpose":{"Cause":{"Adversative":{"Mirative":{}}},"Infinitive":{}}},"E-Necessity":{},"D-Possibility":{"D-Necessity":{}},"Purpose":{"Cause":{"Adversative":{"Mirative":{}}},"Infinitive":{}}},"Pro-Verb":{},"Progressive":{"Habitual":{},"Imperfective":{},"Present":{}}}

const result = getPaths(tDict)

console.log(result)
```